# How to update src of iframe and onclick of link on JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, function

I'm trying to create a page where is would work for both login and sign up at the same with by updating the the src of an iframe.

On the nav bar, I have this:

```
<li id="change"><a onclick="sign()">Sign up</a></li>
```

And on the iframe:

```
<iframe src="loginurl" id="frame"></iframe>
```

Then on the JavaScript, I have this

```
<script>
        function sign(){
                document.getElementById("frame").src="signupurl";
                document.getElementById("change").innerHTML="<a onclick="login()">Login</a>";
        }
        function login(){
                document.getElementById("frame").src="loginurl";
                document.getElementById("change").innerHTML="<a onclick="sign()">Sign up</a>";
        }
</script>
```

Its supposed to change the function it would execute onclick of the sign up link to `login()`
And the src of the iframe and vice versa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a problem of quotes. Try this:

```
function sign() {
  document.getElementById("frame").src = "signupurl";
  document.getElementById("change").innerHTML = '<a onclick="login()">Login</a>';
}

function login() {
  document.getElementById("frame").src = "loginurl";
  document.getElementById("change").innerHTML = '<a onclick="sign()">Sign up</a>';
}
```